# haml-coffee guard plugin issue

Tags: coffeescript, haml, guard, hamlc

When trying to initialize haml-coffee into my Guardfile, I get these messages in my terminal

```
Could not load 'guard/haml-coffee' or '~/.guard/templates/haml-coffee' or find class Guard::Hamlcoffee
ERROR - Error is: No such file or directory - /Users/tommybstitch/.guard/templates/haml-coffee
```

What do I do to get this plugin to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update: version 1.0.0 has been released and should work

---

That plugin is very, very old (2012).

#### Workaround:

You may try to use the last version of Guard that might support it:

```
gem 'guard', '~> 2.7.3'
```

(But there may be other issues with other gems - you may need to downgrade those as well)

#### Fixing the issue:

I've created a branch with some updates (may work), but I'm not the owner of the gem, so I can't make a release:

https://github.com/guard/guard-haml-coffee/tree/major_project_update

You can check out that branch and install the gem locally with:

```
bundle exec rake install
```

Here's the issue if you want to track it: https://github.com/ouvrages/guard-haml-coffee/pull/5

(And given I even get a response from the author)

#### Other:

I'm not sure if any other plugin help (probably not), but check out:

https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Guard-Plugins

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! I saw your pull request before I even noticed you replied on here, actually. 

I am still getting the same error I was getting, but in a different location now: `$ ERROR - Error is: No such file or directory - /Users/tommybonderenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/guard-haml-coffee-0.2.0/lib/guard/hamlcoffee/templates/Guardfile` Also: `ERROR - Could not load 'guard/haml-coffee' or '~/.guard/templates/haml-coffee' or find class Guard::Hamlcoffee
`

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I've just added a commit with a fix - just pull and run `bundle exec rake install` again and it should work.

Comment: You are a saint, my friend. Thank you so, so much for your help! It worked :)